# Javascript Regex optional character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex pattern that I'm using (got it from Stack Overflow) to extract a video ID from a vimeo URL:

```
var regExp = /http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
```

I need it to work whether http or https is specified. I've tried

```
var regExp = /http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/;
```

But this fails on both http and https.

Help a brother out.

Comment: Can you try: `var regExp = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)/;`

Comment: Surprised why `(s)?` doesn't match and `s?` does. There is just a difference of capture group.

Comment: @RohitJain See my answer, it's not because it doesn't match anymore, but because the capturing groups indexes would change, returning the wrong match to the OP if he did not mofidy the rest of his code.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It fails because you are creating an extra capturing group, meaning that the capturing group indexes will not be the same as before.

To make the `s` optionnal without creating a capturing group, you can simply add `?`, you do not need the parenthesis.

```
/https?:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/
```

To create a non-capturing group, you can use `(?:)`, but that's not necessary here, just showing for the example:

```
/http(?:s)?:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/
```

Answer (score 22):

if you want to make "s" option, use only

```
s?
```

i.e., `https?` will match http and https

Comment: the ? means that the char is optional. so it will cover http or https

Comment: That doesn't necessarily explain how it works.

Here you go  :)

https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html

Answer (score 5):

This regex should work:

```
var regExp = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)/;
```